# How to change menu font size in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, treeview, ttk

I want a bigger size for menu's items. It works for menu's commands but also limited size. For example if I set font = 200 it's no difference than font = 50.

```
class Window(Frame):
    #define constructor
    def __init__(self, master):
    
        #initialize class's attributes
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        
    def login(self):
        pass
    
    def menu_function(self):
        #create main menu
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = menu)
        booking       = Menu(menu)
        file          = Menu(menu)
        statistics    = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label = "Exit", font = 50)
        statistics.add_command(label = "Age", font = 50)
        statistics.add_command(label = "Gender", font = 50)
        statistics.add_command(label = "Interests", font = 50)
        menu.add_cascade(label = "Booking", menu = booking)
        menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file)
        menu.add_cascade(label = "Statistics", menu = statistics)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the font *size* without using a custom font *face*, you can use a tuple for the `font` argument, like this: `("", 50)`. Here's a complete working example implementing your class, setting the font size for all menu labels:

```py
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    #define constructor
    def __init__(self, master):
    
        #initialize class's attributes
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        
    def login(self):
        pass
    
    def menu_function(self):
        #create main menu
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu = menu)
        booking       = Menu(menu)
        file          = Menu(menu)
        statistics    = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label = "Exit", font = ("", 50))
        statistics.add_command(label = "Age", font = ("", 50))
        statistics.add_command(label = "Gender", font = ("", 50))
        statistics.add_command(label = "Interests", font = ("", 50))
        menu.add_cascade(label = "Booking", menu = booking, font = ("", 50))
        menu.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = file, font = ("", 50))
        menu.add_cascade(label = "Statistics", menu = statistics, font = ("", 50))

root = Tk()
frame = Window(root)
frame.pack()
frame.menu_function()
root.mainloop()
```

The `""` in `("", 50)` is the font face; here, it's empty, because there's no need to set the font face. If you want to use a custom face, for example `Mono`, just replace `""` with `"Mono"`.

Comment: Thx, it works for menu's options. But How to change font size of 'Booking', 'File' and 'Statistics' ?

Comment: Same way. You add a `font` argument with `("", 50)`. Like this: `menu.add_cascade(label="Statistics", menu=statistics, font=("", 50))`.

Comment: I did so, but nothing changed...

Comment: @Mihai I updated the answer with a complete working example using your code. When I run it on my system, all the menu items are large, as they should be.

Comment: Do you use Windows ? By complete answer you mean using font as you described above ?

Comment: @Mihai The code in my answer above runs perfectly on my system, which is an Ubuntu 20.04. By "running perfectly", I mean that any and all text in the entire window, including that in the menu, is very large.